# Are there alternatives way of power a Raspberry Pi 2 except the microUSB connector?

Tags: power, pi-2, alternative-power

The Arduino can be powered via USB, power jack or VIN/GND pins.

Does the Raspberry PI 2 offer options for power other than the microUSB connector ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

- You can power it via the ground and 5V pins on the expansion header.
- Once it's booted you can also back power it via the USB (although I
  doubt that this is sensible).

Both those methods bypass any protection afforded by the 2 amp polyfuse.

Comment: Thank you(+1). Good to know, although bypassing protection sounds like looking for trouble :)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza: It is most definitely asking for trouble.  If you bypass the polyfuse, you need to make sure than your own circuitry will handle that.  It's doable, but a pain.

Comment: @Joan, is it correct that you can theoretically also power the rPi over the 3.3V pin, as the broadcom itself runs on 3.3V? I recall having read this somewhere.

Comment: @PhilB. Yes, the Pi itself only needs just over 3V.  The USB ports, HDMI etc. need 5V to work properly.  See http://www.daveakerman.com/?p=1154 for someone running off 3V.